# What does the matrix derivative of this equation look like?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to solve this minimization problem:

$$ \min_{\Theta} \frac{C_1}{2} \sum_j^N ||\vec{\theta_j}||^2 $$

where $\Theta = (\vec{\theta_1}, \vec{\theta_2}, ..., \vec{\theta_N})$. (FYI, it's from this [paper](http://papersdb.cs.ualberta.ca/~papersdb/uploaded_files/1060/paper_nips11_survival.pdf)). To find the min, either directly or by Newton's method, I need to differentiate w.r.t $\Theta$. What does the derivative look like? I know it's simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objective function is just the sum of the squares of the elements in $\Theta$, so you can write it in terms of the [Frobenius product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product), for which the differential and derivative are easily found:
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= \frac {C_1} {2} \Theta : \Theta \cr
 df &= {C_1} \Theta : d\Theta \cr
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial \Theta} &= {C_1} \Theta \cr
} $$

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out.

$$ \sum_j^N ||\vec{\theta_j}||^2  = \text{Tr}(\Theta \Theta^T) $$

From there I can use a matrix derivative identity.